# Nebular token endpoint missing client id

Tags: django-rest-framework, nebular

I'm using **Nebular** and **Django** API.

I have following auth strategy setup

```
  NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
    name: 'oauth',
    baseEndpoint: `${environment.apiURL}auth/`,
    clientId: `${environment.clientId}`,
    clientSecret: `${environment.clientSecret}`,
    clientAuthMethod: NbOAuth2ClientAuthMethod.BASIC,
    redirect: {
      success: '/',
      failure: null,
    },
    token: {
      endpoint: 'token/',
      grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.PASSWORD,
      class: NbAuthOAuth2Token,
    },
  }),
```

The endpoint should accept `client_id` and `client_secret` in order to login.

The postman payload is

[image]

But the Nebular request has following data

```
body: "grant_type=password&username=test%40example.com&password=test1234"
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(2), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(2), lazyInit: null}
method: "POST"
params: HttpParams {updates: null, cloneFrom: null, encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec, map: Map(0)}
reportProgress: false
responseType: "json"
```

The body is missing `client_id` and `client_secret`. How can I add the `client_id` and `client_secret`?

Answer (score 0):

The `client_id` and `client_secret` would not be in the body of the request.  You have set `clientAuthMethod: NbOAuth2ClientAuthMethod.BASIC` which will add these values to the `Authorization` header.

If you looked at the headers of the request it would have a header formatted something like this...

```
Authorization Basic <base64-encoded-string (client_id:client_secret)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set client auth to be provided in the request body as:

```
...NbAuthModule.forRoot({
    strategies: [
      NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.setup({
        clientId: environment.auth.clientId,
        clientSecret: environment.auth.clientSecret,
        clientAuthMethod: NbOAuth2ClientAuthMethod.REQUEST_BODY,
        name: 'email',
        baseEndpoint: environment.serverBaseUrL,
        token: {
          endpoint: '/api/oauth/token',
          grantType: NbOAuth2GrantType.PASSWORD,
          ...
        },
      }),
    ],
```